# Qual è il significato di "rubrica" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Dottor Niù. Corsivi diabolici per tragedie evitabili* di Stefano Benni ho trovato l'espressione "[riempire una rubrica](https://books.google.es/books?hl=it&id=ENbfCgAAQBAJ&q=%22riempito+la+rubrica%22#v=snippet&q=%22riempito%20la%20rubrica%22&f=false)". Ecco il brano in cui appare:

> In due mesi, i telefonini hanno enormemente mutato le loro funzioni, dice Niù. Dopo che si sarà collegato alla rete, avrà mandato un fax, **avrà riempito la rubrica** con novecento nomi, avrà comprato i biglietti della partita e avrà giocato al serpentone mangiacoda, pensa di avere ancora il tempo di telefonare?

Non capisco bene il significato di "rubrica" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in alcuni dizionari, comunque mi sa che in questo contesto ha un senso associato alle nuove tecnologie che non ho trovato (o non ho saputo trovare) nei vocabolari che ho consultato. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Il [serpentone mangiacoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29)!

Comment: Significato 3 in http://treccani.it/vocabolario/rubrica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si sta parlando della *rubrica telefonica*. Originariamente un libretto in cui una persona annotava i numeri di telefono, nel contesto dei telefonini è utilizzato principalmente per indicare il menu che contiene la lista dei numeri salvati nella scheda SIM o nella memoria del telefono.

Ecco un [esempio](http://www.navigaweb.net/2013/08/sincronizzare-la-rubrica-su-android.html) (scelto completamente a caso dai risultati di Google per *rubrica telefonica*).

Nel mio telefonino per esempio *Rubrica* indica il menu che nella versione in inglese è chiamato *Contacts* e nella versione in catalano *Contactes*.